# Firebase UI AuthUI.getInstance() throw NPE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I use latest Firebase (11.8.0), and Firebase UI (3.2.1) to display user authentication like this:

```
val providers = Arrays.asList<AuthUI.IdpConfig>(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().setDefaultCountryIso("id").build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())

val intent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo)
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build()

startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.RC_SIGN_IN)
```

This code work, but on Android 19, this code give me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 3357
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.setFirebaseUIVersion(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.setFirebaseUIVersion(Unknown Source)
  at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.<init>(AuthUI.java:208)
  at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance(AuthUI.java:244)
  at com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance(AuthUI.java:232)
  at com.my.app.ui.activity.main.MainActivity$showLoginPrompt$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:454)
  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I discover that the error coming from this `AuthUI.getInstance()`, I try to call a method like this `val auth = AuthUI.getInstance()` then the force close message appear.

Comment: latest Firebase (11.8.0), and Firebase UI (3.2.1)

Comment: Ensure that the device you are testing on has a version of Google Play services that is compatible with Firebase 11.8.0. Look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`

Comment: Are you using an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: I am using emulator, it appear this is only @BobSnyder was right, it because outdated Google Play services

Comment: Yeah, old emulators don't have recent Play services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, it turns out, the cause is outdated Google Play Service version on the emulator I use, When I run my app on real device with updated Google Play Service, no such error occurred.